# Custom EqualityContract in a C# record class

Tags: c#, record, equality, c#-9.0

What is the proper way and the intended use of providing a custom implementation for the `System.Type EqualityContract { get; }` property in a C# record class?

The default (synthesized) implementation returns `typeof(R)` for a record class `R`. Because of that, instances of type `R` can be compared only with other instances of type `R`, otherwise the result is always `false`. This makes perfect sense in typical cases. However, replacing that default implementation by a custom one is allowed, so there must be a reason for that. I would expect it is to allow several record classes to share the equality contract, e.g., if they have the same instance properties or they derive from the same base record class. However, this would require declaring custom overrides of `bool Equals(object? other)` and `bool Equals(Base? other)`, which is forbidden.

[EDIT: Note that the question is about the purpose and usability of defining a custom equality contract. The example below is only to show a potential use which however does not work. I am not asking how to make the example work using a different mechanism.]

For example, suppose I want a record class `Derived` to reuse the equality contract of its base record class `Base` in order to allow comparisons between instances of `Base` and `Derived` based on the instance properties of `Base`. I would need to do something like this:

```
record Base(int X);

record Derived(int X) : Base(X) {
    protected override System.Type EqualityContract => base.EqualityContract;
    public virtual bool Equals(Derived? other) => base.Equals(other);
    public sealed override bool Equals(Base? other) => base.Equals(other); // forbidden
    public override bool Equals(object? other) => base.Equals(other);      // forbidden
    /* some additional stuff */
}
```

I cannot do that because declaring custom overrides of `Equals` is forbidden in C# records. Without the forbidden custom overrides, the record class `Derived` looks as follows (with synthesized overrides of `Equals` included for illustration):

```
record Derived(int X) : Base(X) {
    protected override System.Type EqualityContract => base.EqualityContract;
    public virtual bool Equals(Derived? other) => base.Equals(other);
    public sealed override bool Equals(Base? other) => Equals((object)other); // synthesized
    public override bool Equals(object? other) => Equals(other as Derived);   // synthesized
    /* some additional stuff */
}
```

Then the equality contract does not work correctly. For example, the following code produces `True False`:

```
Base obj1 = new Base(1);
Derived obj2 = new Derived(1);
System.Console.WriteLine($"{obj1 == obj2} {obj2 == obj1}");
```

Both comparisons use the operator `==` of `Base`, which calls the method `bool Equals(Base? other)`. For `obj1 == obj2`, the implementation from `Base` is used, which compares the equality contracts (equal in this case) and the values of `X` (equal in this case) and returns `true`. For `obj2 == obj1`, the implementation from `Derived` is used, which results in a call to `obj2.Equals(obj1 as Derived)`, which returns `false`, because `obj1 as Derived` is `null`.

So how am I supposed to make use of custom equality contracts? Is there anything I am missing? What would be wrong with allowing custom overrides to `Equals`?

I have searched through the discussions in the C# design repository to find some information. The only two relevant comments I have found indicate that my scenario above was intended to work:
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3137#issuecomment-581558013
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3787#discussioncomment-130523

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand as of .NET6 you cannot implement mirrored equality for records. You can get `true` for `base1 == derived1` using `EqualityContract`, as you have shown, but the other way is not possible.

The problem is that while `Equals(Derived? other)` in `Derived` will be called it will be called with `null` for `derived1 == base1` and as you rightly point out overriding the other `Equals` is forbidden.

In my opinion this is not problem because:

1. Having a derived record that has no extra fields is questionable.
2. If the records have different flields then compare-only-x behavior would be confusing.

---

The solution for your issue may a custom equality comparer. *(In case you don't know about them, the official [EqualityComparer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1) has an excellent example with two dictionaries for the same type but with different equality comparers.)*

Having:

```
record Base(int X) {}

record Derived(int X, int Y) : Base(X) {}

class CheckOnlyXComparer : EqualityComparer<Base>
{
    public override bool Equals(Base? b1, Base? b2)
    {
        if (b1 == null && b2 == null) return true;
        if (b1 == null || b2 == null) return false;
        return (b1.X == b2.X);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Base b) => b.X.GetHashCode();
}
```

the following snippet

```
WriteLine(base1 == derived1);
WriteLine(derived1 == base1);

var comparer = new CheckOnlyXComparer();
WriteLine(comparer.Equals(base1,derived1));
WriteLine(comparer.Equals(derived1,derived1));
```

prints

```
False
False
True
True
```

---

For

```
List<Base> l1 = new (){base1, derived1};
WriteLine(l1.Count());
var distinctByX = l1.Distinct(new CheckOnlyXComparer());
WriteLine(distinctByX.Count());
```

we get

```
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the point of my question is to understand the purpose of defining a custom equality contract, not to make the Base/Derived example work using a different mechanism. I am rather looking for something that would demonstrate the use of defining a custom equality contract, and the example is only to show a potential use which however does not work. Also, my question why custom overrides to Equals are forbidden still stands.

Comment: Your point about about forbidden absolutely stands. I'd say it's worth having a separate question about this that **only** asks why they are forbidden.

Comment: My answer focused on providing a solution - and I'll allow myself to say it's an elegant one ;) , and confirming your investigation.

Comment: `EqualityContract` allows derived types to 'disable' the type check for `base == derived` and IMHO it provides good value already.

Comment: What does it mean that `EqualityContract` allows derived types to 'disable' the type check for `base == derived`? I don't understand.

Comment: I agree that your modification of the example is elegant. It is a pity it needs to make member-by-member comparisons instead of making use of the synthesized equality.